# How to correctly use *blockquotes* in questions/answers?

Tags: discussion

It seems I can't manage to use *blockquotes* correctly in my answers. There's always an extra empty row in the blockquote. I thank the editors for their patience and perseverance in correcting my answers. This situation is beginning to haunt me.

I use the `>` sign to begin the blockquote, but I found no method of ending it properly. The `<` sign doesn't work and I really don't know what to do / how to do it correctly.

Comment: I tend to rely on the code button, which looks like `{ }` in the top bar of the Question/Answer panel.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Answer (score 4):

Please see [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) for help on formatting your posts. That said, you don't need to close the blockquote. Just leave an empty line and the next one will be normal.

For example, this:

```
> this is a blockquote

But this isn't
```

Renders like this:

> this is a blockquote

But this isn't

Comment: My problem is exactly the empty line. It always appear 'in grey' space, like it belongs to the blockquote, not to the 'normal' white space. At least a dozens answers like that have been corrected by the editors for that single reason.

Comment: @ipselute please post an example of this in your question so we can understand what the problem is.

Comment: Just an example:  http://askubuntu.com/posts/786181/revisions

Comment: @ipselute I don't understand. The editor there, correctly, changed your quote to code. That's not what your question here is about. Please edit your question and show an example. Explain what you expected to see and how it differs from what you actually see.

Comment: Just another example: http://askubuntu.com/posts/787276/revisions.  This kind of situation happens a lot, but not in all answers. I just don't get, why some blockquotes are fine, and others get changed to code?

Comment: @ipselute I will ask you for the third time. Please **edit your question and add an example**. None of the examples you've shown make sense. You were using blockquotes (`>`) to format code instead of code formatting and that's what the editors changed. Is that what's confusing you? Have you read the [page](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) I linked to? That explains when to use one and when the other.